# how to active a class onclick list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am facing a problem in which i want to add class onclick means the clicked should add class.
see my image
[image]

i am doing this by jquery as:

```
$(function() {

$('.box li').click(function(){
    $('.box li').removeClass('submenu-active');

    $(this).addClass('submenu-active');

});

});
```

and my css is:

```
.aside ul li.submenu-active a {background-color:#df0000; color:#fff;}
```

and my submenu code is:

```
<ul class="box">
                <li class="submenu-active"><a href="create_financial_year.php">Create Financial Year</a></li>
                <li ><a href="select_financial_year.php">Select Financial Year</a></li>
                <li><a href="account_master.php">Account Master</a></li>
                <li><a href="bank_account_master.php">Bank Account Master</a></li> <!-- Active -->                  
                <li><a href="subscription_master.php">Subscription Master</a></li>
                <li><a href="subscription_fee_master.php">Subscription Fee Master</a></li>
                <li><a href="member_master.php">Member Master</a></li>                
                <li><a href="membership_suspension.php">Membership Suspension</a></li>
            </ul>
```

i realy Have spent so many hour but did not sort out this...**by this it is working but when i leave click onmouse then the added class got remove...**
any suggestion would be highly responsive...thanxxx

Comment: the part in bold is not really clear... could you rephrase the problem you're facing?

Comment: i want that when i click list item then background color of list item should be red.....

Answer (score 5):

Use that instead:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ywgpB/1/)

```
$(function () {

    $('.box li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('submenu-active').siblings().removeClass('submenu-active');
        //to load new content using ajax
        //you could wish to show user, some content is loading
        $('#myContainer').html('<img src="loading.gif>').load(this.href);
    });

});
```

Corresponding CSS for your jsfiddle:

```
ul.box li.submenu-active {
    background-color:#df0000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Problem is then, anchor tags won't redirect to corresponding page, but i don't know what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: Usually, for this kind of purpose, we use ajax methods as load() to render html of specific element as a container. You can otherwise just  then  redirect to the new page but then all your javascript here for styling is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`.aside ul li.submenu-active a`
to
`li.submenu-active a`

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/rGjLs/).

Comment: I change it the href to `#` so it won't leave JSFiddle on a click. If you change the href's to the right ones, it will work. But concider the answer insertusernahmehere gives... when the link is clicked, your page will load the new page, and the highlight will be gone.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function toggleColor() {
  var button = document.querySelector('a');
  button.classList.toggle('blue');
}
//if you only want to add a class instead of toggling one write the code below

function changeColor() {
  var button = document.querySelector('a');
  button.classList.add('blue');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff0fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.4s;
}

a.blue {
  background: #0f57ff;
  transition: background-color 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggleColor();">Click To Toggle Colors</a>
```

Comment: `<a onclick="toggleColor();">` will cause issues, it should. be `<a onclick="toggleColor">` or `<a onclick="() => toggleColor();">`

Comment: Also, this is not jQuery and is not contextually answering the question.